# Warning - Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4 for Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, testng-eclipse

I created a Java project with Eclipse Helios, including a number of Selenium test cases. It worked fine for a day but then this warning showed up:

> Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

I was able to run my test case. However, to remove this warning, I followed some steps I found from someone else:

> In Eclipse from your project:
>
> Right-click on your project
>   Click Properties
>   Java build path: Libraries; Remove the "JRE System Library[J2SE 1.4]"
>   Click Add Library -> JRE System Library
>
> Select the new "Execution Environment" or Workspace default JRE

Now I am not able to run my test cases, and I get the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)
>
> The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Why is your question tagged [tag:selenium] and not [tag:java]? The question does not mention Selenium. This looks more like a general Java question than a test-related question.

Comment: i am writing test case with selenium and java

Comment: Eclipse Helios is seriously old...